# remove Fetching JavaScript bundle in react-native run-windows

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, react-native, runtime-error, react-native-windows

I have a problem when building Release in Visual Studio through the react-native run-windows project ..

I have done a Release bundle and there is also project.appx. But when I run the application, Fetching JavaScript bundle appears, even though it's already in release mode ...

The problem is, how do I get rid of the Fetching JavaScript bundle so that the application can run without going through the Fetching JavaScript Bundle ..?

Hopefully I can get a solution here.

thank you